# Font Awesome 4.1.0 not working in Cordova android emulator

Tags: android, css, cordova, fonts, font-awesome

I can't figure out why Font Awesome icons aren't showing up in my cordova app.

I downloaded the entire font-awesome folder and copied it to my project's folder. I've included the folder with:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

I am certain this is correct because `<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>` will display in chrome perfectly fine.

However when I run `cordova emulate android` the icons don't show up in my android emulator.

I then tried following the troubleshooting here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting

It seems that the troubleshooting thinks this is an error related to `text-rendering`, but when I add `text-rendering: auto;` to `.fa { }` in both the minified and the full css, I still don't see the icons in my android emulator.

I'm at a loss of what to do. My android target project is 4.4.2 api level 19. Can anyone help?

Here's the html section related to the icons.

```
<body> 
    <div id="main">
           <div id="top">
               <i id="settings" class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
               <p id="logo" > Chowza Inc </p>
          </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: can you take an example font from `font-awesome.min.css` file, place it inside the <style> tag of your html file and check whether it works?

Comment: @frank hmmm when I try `font-family: 'FontAwesome';` it seems like nothing is changing...do you know what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I copied the FontAwesome folder into my project folder but when using `cordova emulate android` the Font Awesome folder was not being built. Copying the FontAwesome folder into the CSS folder and changing the related link paths corrected this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue on android 4.0.3 cordova app. In my case I had to remove version parameter (v=4.1.0) from the url.
For example:

> **Old block in font-awesome.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

> **New block in font-awesome.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```